# Select count of subquery results, along with another field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a query that selects the distinct IDs of a parent resource, while being able to filter and sort the results of its child tables. The basic structure of the query looks as follows:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (work_items.id) work_items.id, work_item_states.id AS work_item_states_id
    FROM work_items
    JOIN work_item_states ON work_item_states.work_item_refer = work_items.id
    WHERE work_item_states.disposition = 'cancelled'
    ORDER BY work_items.id
) AS s
ORDER BY s.work_item_states_id DESC
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0
```

Note: the columns, filters, joins, etc in this query are just examples for explanation purposes. These queries will be completely different as they support arbitrary data. Only the basic structure of the query stays the same.

For pagination purposes, I need to be able to count the total results of the subquery. For now, I've just been using a whole separate query for that, as follows, with the same example as above:

```
SELECT COUNT(s)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (work_items.id) work_items.id, work_item_states.id AS work_item_states_id
    FROM work_items
    JOIN work_item_states ON work_item_states.work_item_refer = work_items.id
    WHERE work_item_states.disposition = 'cancelled'
    ORDER BY work_items.id
) AS s
```

This is rather inefficient, as I will be working with databases with millions of entries. Does anyone know how I can combine these two kinds of queries, such that the result returns both the IDs and the count of the subqueries?
Something like:

```
SELECT s.id, COUNT(s)
```

is what I'm looking for, but that just gives me a count of 1 for each ID in the results.

Thanks

Comment: You mean you do this 2 query separate operation and you want to make it as 1?

Comment: Try adding WITH ORDINALITY to the query, e.g., select * from generate_series(1000,1010) with ordinality;

Comment: Use a common table expressions? `with cte1 as (....),  cte2 as (select count(*) from cte1 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible (and easiest) to do this with a window function. Taking your initial query and ignoring the specifics of what's in the middle of it:

```
SELECT s.id, s.total_item_count
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (work_items.id) work_items.id
     , work_item_states.id AS work_item_states_id
     , count(work_items.id) over () as total_item_count
    FROM work_items
    JOIN work_item_states ON work_item_states.work_item_refer = work_items.id
    WHERE work_item_states.disposition = 'cancelled'
    ORDER BY work_items.id
) AS s
ORDER BY s.work_item_states_id DESC
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0
```

Note that window functions are applied *after* `group by` or `distinct on` constructions (and even after filtering with the `having` clause), and so will give you the number of rows returned by the subquery rather than the number of rows in the working table of `work_items` joined with `work_item_states` before the distinct rows or other aggregates are taken. Because of this you can actually use aggregate functions within window functions.

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question perfectly.